# Is possible to identify a transaction that deploy a new token in BSCScan API?

Tags: bsc, explorer-api

I have access to the BSCScan API to take last transactions by calling for the last block:

https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=proxy&action=eth_blockNumber

Result:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": 83,
"result": "0x6d7138"
}
```

So I call the API again to see last block transactions (I presume they are the last transactions at all):

```
https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getBlockByNumber&tag=0x6d7138&boolean=true&apikey=<MY_API_KEY>
```

Result (partial):

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": 1,
"result": {
"difficulty": "0x2",
"extraData": "0xd883010006846765746888676f312e31352e35856c696e7578000000fc3ca6b721df73705c7a4c0c4c69bb9d443a2d9431d6af69efd3e88f707830c919b9d48c7ef50acea5401d3c4691d4f0dc04d49190ffdad766715e9197fcce8d5725adaa00",
"gasLimit": "0x2a9d887",
"gasUsed": "0x13577e6",
"hash": "0x814280a50dd15e2d7c577443755d8c4d04e06404bd34758457b491734ff6f5d6",
"logsBloom": "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",
"miner": "0x70f657164e5b75689b64b7fd1fa275f334f28e18",
"mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"nonce": "0x0000000000000000",
"number": "0x6d6faa",
"parentHash": "0x145593cb7c173573753ecbf4edba0bb94e8c439c9a341a6f3ac8cd5a23dcd591",
"receiptsRoot": "0x19cfdd8c4e818197bd6d3fbee1b934628bf902c7979b03f6bec4ca83b4a185c5",
"sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
"size": "0x12f01",
"stateRoot": "0x7ae1ef174f6c9333de03759f4384fdc36cf6cabc956727046c1279fc2576559d",
"timestamp": "0x60933ac2",
"totalDifficulty": "0xda5787",
"transactions": [
{
"blockHash": "0x814280a50dd15e2d7c577443755d8c4d04e06404bd34758457b491734ff6f5d6",
"blockNumber": "0x6d6faa",
"from": "0x000000a0c521dd28025b937b1f15141d61969959",
"gas": "0x493e0",
"gasPrice": "0x5d21dba00",
"hash": "0x5fdf16feb5d044603c821312e38b1db95a9f6bee35a012d08476d17a2a2ce538",
"input": "0x38ed17390000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006c53ced68a312000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006abbea5d4c723400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000000000a0c521dd28025b937b1f15141d619699590000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060933ac60000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c0000000000000000000000007083609fce4d1d8dc0c979aab8c869ea2c873402",
"nonce": "0x3abdc",
"to": "0xc0788a3ad43d79aa53b09c2eacc313a787d1d607",
"transactionIndex": "0x0",
"value": "0x0",
"v": "0x93",
"r": "0x6912203611a43fb110b8b1f8057c8cd92fb893db706342bf380670fa9370700e",
"s": "0x1a90b45b8c0d602253281d32e512a594ec05697a4cf1ef6e227d0b5db9edc97c"
},
```

So ... is possible to check that TX and tell it is a token deploy? My goal is to know when a new token arrives on the chain.

I found this kind of address "Contract Creation" but don't know what is it.

[image]

**EDIT**

Well.. seems I can't figure out how to find the token contract address by looking the creation transaction.

[image]

Here I can see the TX `0xa675342c579fe2424be52b861bb9acd9acb6f98ff79eb99177000a2438b28487` was creted the contract `0x0ff5c3bffea73b562a9ec897e78b6a650fafd104` but there is no reference to this hash in block `7173853` as you can check here: https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getBlockByNumber&tag=0x6D76DD&boolean=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After give a look [here](https://bnbsmartchain.com/binance-smart-chain-dapp-dev-tutorial-part-ii-how-to-create-a-bep20-token/) and check [this log](https://bscscan.com/address/0x7e44363dd109e6be5afff552e4986ca84806f79f) and [this transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x4c88818f195b6c6bdcaa1079cfca4b770b5a989c8bd6c204bcc005c2291653c2) I tempted to conclude I'm just need to check the data of transaction. I conclude all contract deployment data I found starts with "`0x60806040527f76`".

Actually.... this is the start of the contract code...most like "pragma solidity bla bla bla" so this must be the Solidity version.

I discovered the "TO" attribute is null for contract deployments ...

Comment: I'm stuck here. I have no way to link the transaction that created the token with the token contract address.

Answer (score 0):

You can find contract creation transaction by the **to** field: this is always `null` for contract creation.

After this step you should get the transaction receipt of the contract creation transaction which contains the contract address: https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionReceipt&txhash=0xa675342c579fe2424be52b861bb9acd9acb6f98ff79eb99177000a2438b28487